# Selection sort strings from string object array without importing anything other than Scanner (code provided)?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object

```
    public static String sorting(){
    for (int i = 0; i < pigArray.length; i++){
        for (int k = i + 1; k <pigArray.length; k++){

            if(pigArray[k].getName().trim().compareTo(pigArray[i].getName().trim())< 0){
                String temp = pigArray[i].getName();
                pigArray[i].getName() = pigArray[k].getName;
                pigrray[k].getName();
            }
        }
    }

    String sorted = "";

    for (int m = 0; m < pigArray.length; m++){

        sorted = sorted + "\n" + pigArray[m].getName();     
    }

    return sorted
}
```

I have this code right here. I need the `pigArray[].getName` to call the names store in that object array (so I cant just replace that with `pigArray[]`). I want it to sort in alphabetical order and figured this would work. But there is a red line underneath `pigArray[i].getName` (from the line: `pigArray[i].getName() = pigArray[k].getName;`) and says that it has to be a variable. I am so lost. Any tips are appreciated. Thank you. (no arraylist, hashset, maps, etc. because I want to master the basics before importing any other packages)

Comment: `getName` is a method which returns `name` I presume ?

Comment: getName is a method returning name

Comment: You'll need to use `pigArray[i].setName(pigArray[k].getName();` And your following lone call to pigArray[k].getName() is going to do nothing, btw. That getter will just return its value to nobody and be sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign value to method call. It does not work like that.

You need to create s `setter` for name variable.

```
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Then your `if` block  would be

```
if(pigArray[k].getName().trim().compareTo(pigArray[i].getName().trim())< 0){
            String temp = pigArray[i].getName();
            pigArray[i].setName( pigArray[k].getName );
            pigrray[k].setName(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

pigArray[i].getName() is not a variable. If you want to modify the object, modify the array like pigArray[i] = something. getName() only returns the value. You can not modify the value returned by it